# Traversing parent-child nodes with xpath using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an html similar to following

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='1'>
        <div>
            <a class='abc'> element1 </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class='2'></td>
    <td class='3'>
        <img id='generated id' class='xyz' />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have element1 coming as a parameter to a function. When I get element1, I need to traverse to img tag and click on it.

I tried the xpath selector

```
WebElement e = driver.getelementbyXpath("//a[contains(@class,'abc')
and text()='element1')"]);

WebElement e2 = e1.findelementbyxpath("../..//img[contains(@id,'something') 
and contains(@class='xyz')]");
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your "element1" text node has space paddings at both sides. 
`"//a[contains(@class,'abc') and text()=' element1 ')"` would've worked ;)

Besides, you used too much `contains`, which I believe is quite inefficient comparing to `[@class='abc']` `[@id='blah..']`.

Comment: This is probably it, but I would go one step further and use normalize-space to trim the property's (the text property of the element) value for you: `//a[contains(@class,'abc')
and normalize-space(text())='element1')`